# XSLT copy-of without duplicates

Tags: xml, xslt

I am completely new to XSLT so please bear with me.

I have two xml files that I am attempting to concatenate together using XSLT.  I would like to combine the files such that any values specified in the second file override the first.  E.g.

**firstFile.xml**

```
<person>
  <person-name>Sandy</person-name>
  <person-age>21</person-age>
</person>

<person>
  <person-name>Bob</person-name>
  <person-age>15</person-age>
</person>
```

**override.xml**

```
<person>
  <person-name>Bob</person-name>
  <person-age>21</person-age>
</person>
```

**Result:**

```
<person>
  <person-name>Sandy</person-name>
  <person-age>21</person-age>
</person>
<person>
  <person-name>Bob</person-name>
  <person-age>21</person-age>
</person>
```

My template for concatenating the 2 files is as follows:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <!-- MainFile -->
     <xsl:copy-of select="/*"/>

      <!-- Overrides-->
      <xsl:copy-of select="document($overrideFile)/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

I was attempting to setup a for-each loop such that before copying each person in firstFile.xml check if there is a corresponding node in override.xml, but was unsuccessful.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDoc2Url" select="'file:///c:/temp/delete/override.xml'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="document($pDoc2Url)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <t>
    <xsl:apply-templates
       select="person[not(person-name = $vDoc2/*/person/person-name)]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc2/*/person"/>
  </t>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the first of the provided XML documents** (wrapped into a single top element -- to be made a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <person>
        <person-name>Sandy</person-name>
        <person-age>21</person-age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <person-name>Bob</person-name>
        <person-age>15</person-age>
    </person>
</t>
```

**and being passed as parameter the filename where the second document (again wrapped into a top element) resides -- here is the corrected second document**:

**c:/temp/delete/override.xml**:

```
<t>
    <person>
        <person-name>Bob</person-name>
        <person-age>21</person-age>
    </person>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<t>
   <person>
      <person-name>Sandy</person-name>
      <person-age>21</person-age>
   </person>
   <person>
      <person-name>Bob</person-name>
      <person-age>21</person-age>
   </person>
</t>
```

---

**II. A shorter, but less flexible solution -- no identity rule and no `xsl:apply-templates`**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDoc2Url" select="'file:///c:/temp/delete/override.xml'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="document($pDoc2Url)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <t>
    <xsl:copy-of
       select="person[not(person-name = $vDoc2/*/person/person-name)]"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vDoc2/*/person"/>
  </t>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Dimitre!  For some reason my brain has difficulty thinking in XSLT!  Debugging hasn't been very easy for me either, I've been trying to use IntelliJ + XSLT Debugger with no success.

Comment: @DerekGourlay, You are welcome. There are different XSLT IDEs. For XSLT 1.0 one can use the MS Visual Studio XML Editor and XSLT Debugger. I am using another one -- the XSelerator. Many people use oXygen which provides both XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 1.0 debuggers -- using Saxon.